# How to limit the number of windows a button can open?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter and python in general. I am making an application and need a 'settings' button.
This is how I create it:

```
buttonSettings = Button(win, text=txtSettings, command=lambda: create_window(win))
buttonSettings.grid(row=1, column=4)
```

where:

```
def create_window(win):
    window = Toplevel(win)
```

How would I limit to one the number of windows that that button can create?

Comment: Do you just want it to be 1 window? If so you can disable at the time the window opens and then re-enable when the top window closes. If multiple you can just run a check to see how many windows are open before disabling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you will need to add the `window = None` to initialize your object.

```py
window = None

def create_window(win):
    if(not window):
        window = Toplevel(win)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is to be able to open a specific number of windows then consider storing those windows in a list then using `index()` you can pop them from the list on exist.

See below example and let me know if you have questions:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('200x50')
        self.top_windows = []
        tk.Button(self, text='Open window!', command=self.open_top).pack()

    def open_top(self):
        if len(self.top_windows) <= 5:
            top = tk.Toplevel(self)
            self.top_windows.append(top)
            tk.Button(self.top_windows[-1], text='exit',
                      command=lambda top=top: (self.top_windows.pop(self.top_windows.index(top)), top.destroy())).pack()

App().mainloop()
```